# Display text and image with one click a button

Tags: android, image

I have been strugling to learn android studio for two months. I improve a little BUT. I couldnt get my intend yet. I just want to show my text in string file and my image in drawable file only click one button.
is it possible?

```
btn.setOnClickListener(    
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
           //here I want t o display the image in my drawable file
                   and
            // here I want to show my html text in my string file

        }
    }
);
```

thanks image is ok. but text dont work:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View view) {
                                             String myString = getResource().getString(R.strings.delivery_address);
                                             img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb);


                    }
                }
        );

                }
}
```

why getresource and strins are red I also create strings and image file but why getresource and strings are red?

Comment: I didn't get your question . Where do you want to display your image and html content ?

Answer (score -1):

You can set image on button using `android:drawableLeft` attribute

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image"
        android:text="@string/your text"/>
```